# Can't set alt row color on table rows built in success function of $.ajax call

Tags: jquery, tablerow

In the success function of an ajax call I'm .append()ing rows to a table from data retrieved from a php script. Here's the code that builds the rows:

```
$.each(data, function(index,element) {
    $('table#tblMovieList tbody').delay(200).append('<tr class="viewMovieRow">' +
        '<td class="listEditMovie">' +
            '<a class="linkEditMovie" name="' + element['movieID'] + '" href="#">Edit</a>' +
        '</td>' +
        '<td class="listDeleteMovie">' +
            '<input type="checkbox" class="chkDeleteMovie" name="deleteMovies[]" value="' + element['movieID'] + '" />' +
        '</td>' +
        '<td class="listMovieTitle">' +
            element['title'] +
        '</td>' +
        '<td class="listMovieDirector">' +
             ((element['directorFirstName'] === null) ? '' : element['directorFirstName']) + ' ' + ((element['directorLastName'] === null) ? '' : element['directorLastName']) +
        '</td>' +
        '<td class="listMovieLength">' +
            ((element['runTime'] === '0') ? '' : element['runTime']) +
        '</td>' +
        '<td class="listMovieMpaaRating">' +
            ((element['mpaaRating'] === null) ? '' : element['mpaaRating']) +
        '</td>' +
        '<td class="listMovieYearReleased">' +
            ((element['yearReleased'] ===  '0') ? '' : element['yearReleased']) +
        '</td>' +
        '<td class="listMovieSynopsis">' +
            element['synopsis'] +
        '</td>' +
        '<td class="listMovieFormat">' +
            ((element['format'] === null) ? '' : element['format']) +
        '</td>' +
        '<td class="listMovieReleaseStatus">' +
            ((element['releaseStatus'] === null) ? '' : element['releaseStatus']) +
        '</td>' +
        '<td class="listMovieMyRating">' +
            ((element['myRating'] === null) ? '' : element['myRating']) +
        '</td>' +
    '/<tr>');
});
```

Then I'm using this line to attempt to color the even rows in the table:

```
$("#tblMovieList tbody tr:even").addClass("alt");
```

Putting that line right after the .each() function colors **all** of the tbody rows. If I put the line *anywhere* else in the js file, **none** of the rows get colored.

Am I missing something? Is there another way I need to do this since the rows are dynamically built? I created a jsFiddle, but I didn't know how to simulate iterating through an .each() function to build the rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you don't hate CSS, and your users have compliant browsers:

```
#tblMovieList tbody tr:nth-child(even) td {
    background-color: red; /* or whatever */
}
```

And I haven't tried this, but the following *should* work:

```
$('table#tblMovieList tbody')
    .delay(200)
    .append(/* all that table-generating code */)
    .find('tr:even').addClass('alt');
```

This *should* work because the `append()` method returns the element/node to which the content was *appended*, not the newly-added elements; therefore it should add the new elements and then, once added, look to find the `tr:even` elements, and then add the class.

And, incidentally, you *need* to use a function in that generating code, if only to preserve your own sanity when the time comes to maintain or develop that script.

Or the problem might be the incorrectly-closed, or rather *un*-closed `tr` element, the `/<tr>` in the final line of the HTML-construction, which causes jQuery to create a new, empty, row on each iteration. Fixing the mark-up (correcting to `</tr>`) would solve this issue.

References:

- [`:nth-child()` pseudo-class, W3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#nth-child-pseudo).

Comment: @Bhushan, too - Sorry - the nth-child:even and .find() methods didn't work either. This doesn't make sense. I've done this before on dynamically generated rows. I don't understand why none of these is working...

Comment: Then something's going *very* wrong: CSS will, or *should* match, and be independent of the dynamic nature of the HTML. Examine your HTML and make sure that what you're creating is what's getting added, and not being changed by the browser when it's constructing the DOM.

Comment: Looking at the code in Chrome, the class is getting added to **all** of the rows.

Comment: Dumb, dumb, dumb, dumb, dumb. If you look very closely at the second to last line, which closes the table row in the .each() function, you'll see the problem. The slash is in the wrong place! I found it because that was causing an empty row to be created in each iteration.

Comment: @eventide: edited the actual solution into the answer, that way any future visitors don't have to read comments to find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [:nth-child Selector](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) that Selects all elements that are the nth-child of their parent.Check if the table row is even or odd and them apply proper color

```
#tblMovieList tbody tr:nth-child(even) td {
    background-color: yourcolor;
}
```